# Showing a particular function is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove the following. Let $X$ be a measurable space. Given that the the real-valued function f on $X$ is a measurable function, show that the function $f_{A}(x) = \begin{cases}|f(x)|,& |f(x)|\leq A\\ A,& f(x)>A\\ -A,& f(x)<-A\end{cases}$ is measurable given that A is some nonnegative real number.
My attempt is as follows:
$\{x\in X\mid f_{A}(x)>\alpha\} = \{x\in X\mid |f(x)|>\alpha\}\cup\{x\in X\mid f_{A}(x) = A>\alpha\}\cup\{x\in X\mid f_{A}(x) = -A>\alpha\}$. Now since $f$ is measurable and every constant function is measurable, each of these sets in the union is a measurable set and so our function $f_{A}$ is in turn a measurable set.

I want to know if this attempt is correct, especially if this $\{x\in X\mid f_{A}(x)>\alpha\} = \{x\in X\mid |f(x)|>\alpha\}\cup\{x\in X\mid f_{A}(x) = A>\alpha\}\cup\{x\in X\mid f_{A}(x) = -A>\alpha\}$ is true.

**NB:** I am not looking for a solution to the problem as I already have it, I just want to know if my attempt is correct, or if it makes sense at least. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Don't use all cap titles when you don't have to.

Answer (score 2):

The function $x\mapsto |x|$ is continuous, thus measurable; composition of measurable functions are measurable, so $|f|$ is measurable and $\{|f|\leq A\},\{f>A\},\{f<-A\}$ are measurable sets. Constant functions are measurable. Also, sums of measurable functions are measurable and products of measurable functions are measurable. So
$$f_A(x):=|f(x)|\mathbf{1}_{\{|f|\leq A\}}(x)+A\mathbf{1}_{\{f>A\}}(x)-A\mathbf{1}_{\{f<-A\}}(x)$$
is measurable.

---

On your argument: let $(X,\mathscr{A})$ be the measurable space;

Let $\alpha \geq A$. Then $\{f_A>\alpha\}=\emptyset$. Let $A>\alpha \geq 0$, then $\{f_A>\alpha\}=\{\alpha <|f|\leq A\}\cup \{f>A\}$. Let $0>\alpha \geq -A$, then $\{f_A>\alpha\}=\{|f|\leq A\}\cup \{f>A\}$. Let $\alpha <-A$, then $\{f_A>\alpha\}=X$. So for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $\{f_A>\alpha\}\in \mathscr{A}$ and $f_A$ is measurable.